# Material UI custom styles do not apply on the component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have just started learning **Material UI** in **react js**.

When it comes to custom styling, I encounter an issue where everything seems to be logically correct but the styling doesn't apply.

There is a button in **Create.js** component which I'm trying to change its style with the help of `import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles"`

These are the dependencies installed in *package.json*:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.2",
```

Here is **Create.js** component:

```
import React from "react";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { Button, Container } from "@mui/material";
import KeyboardArrowRightIcon from "@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowRight";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const useStyle = makeStyles({
  btn: {
    fontSize: 60,
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
});

export default function Create() {
  const classes = useStyle();

  return (
    <Container>
      <Typography
        variant="h6"
        color="textSecondary"
        align="center"
        gutterBottom
      >
        Create a New Note
      </Typography>
      <Button
        className={classes.btn}
        onClick={() => console.log("you clicked me")}
        type="submit"
        color="secondary"
        variant="contained"
        endIcon={<KeyboardArrowRightIcon />}
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

This is what I see when I inspect the element:

[DevTools keeps ignoring this style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67BFm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The code is so far good. One difference I observed in documentation and the provided code is the import of `makeStyles`. Try importing `makesStyles` from `@mui/styles`. For reference have a look at [documentation](https://mui.com/styles/basics/).

Also MUI is now compatible with plain css for minor tweaks like these. Please refer [here](https://mui.com/guides/interoperability/)

As far as the issue of browser ignoring styles is concerned a workaround can be using `important` keyword in custom styles but that is not a recommended and inefficient way.